# If I select dropdown value and then click on setUpFormTextField my dropdown is reset. How to solve it (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart

If I select dropdown value and then click on `setUpFormTextField` my dropdown is reset. How to solve it  (Flutter)?

```
Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 16),
                            child: setUpDropDown<ContactUsReason>(
                                title: context.getStrings().contactReason,
                                context: context,
                                list: listOfReason,
                                itemWidget: (value) {
                                  return Text(value.reason.toString());
                                },
                                value: listOfReason[0],
                                valueChanged: (values) =>
                                    {contactUsReq.reason_id = values?.id},
    
                                onSaved: (value) =>
                                    {contactUsReq.reason_id = value?.id},
                                validator: DropDownValidator<ContactUsReason>(
                                    context
                                        .getStrings()
                                        .contactReasonSelectionErrorText, (value) {
                                  return value?.id != null;
                                }).get()),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 30),
                          child: setUpFormTextField(
                            controller: _suggestionText,
                              title: context.getStrings().pleaseTellUsYourSuggestion,
                              context: context,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              validator: CompulsoryValidator(
                                      context.getStrings().emptySuggestionErrorText)
                                  .get(),
                              onChanged: (values){
                                    if(values.isNotEmpty){
                                      setState(() {
                                        _suggestionData=values;
                                      });
                                    }
                              },
                              onSaved: (value) {
                                contactUsReq.message = value;
                              })),
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you change value of `setUpFormTextField`, you call `setState`, so the screen is rebuilt and the `setUpDropDown` default value changed to `listOfReason[0]`.
You should define a variable and keep the selected value, or make a query to find the selected id. For example:

```
//make sure you don't put this code in `build` function. You can put in `initState`
var selectedItem = listOfReason[0];
```

and in your dropdown

```
value: selectedItem,
valueChanged: (values){
   selectedItem = values;
   contactUsReq.reason_id = values?.id;
},
```